# Backup & remove specific records - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there anyway to:

1. Remove specific records from the table using a query?
2. Make a backup from specific records and restore them into another SQL Server instance somewhere else?

[image: You can find the attached in below]

Comment: Hint: Use the ID column value.

Comment: Why a backup? Couldn't you just insert into the other DB, you just have to use fully qualified names?

Comment: For some reasons i need to do it @Divi

Comment: @Mehran: You need to explain your requirements better so that you can get a better solution

Comment: I have two systems. i want to copy all the table contents of computer No1. into Computer No2.
I can make a backup or send a jquery for this. But its just make backup the table FieldsName. and its not include all the records in it.
And for some reasons i have to work in in two separated computer with separate SQL server (But both of them have same version of SQL & Database name)

Answer (score 3):

1) If `ID` is the table's PK (or it is unique) you can just use `DELETE FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE ID IN (3, 4)`. You better check if this will not delete other items  (or open a transaction, which is always good).

2) If it is just those 4 records and both databases are on the same server (and both tables have the same schema) you can just do (with the same worries that I have expressed in the answer above)

```
insert into DESTINATION
select * from SOURCE where id between 73 and 76;
```

Edit: If you really need to do something more like a row backup you can use the [bcp utility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx):

```
bcp "select * from SOURCE where id between 73 and 76" queryout "file.dat" -T -c 

bcp DESTINATION in file.dat -T -c
```

Comment: "bcp" was the lifesaver for me. It uses a transactional "all or none" approach and rolls back if anything goes wrong when restoring the records

Answer (score 1):

DELETE FROM ListsItems
WHERE ID = (3, 4);

It will remove your record.

Modify it....

Comment: should also append 'OR ID = 4'